# How to use a case statement to display a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display a partial based on the value of a model.

```
<% if @user.new_record? %>
  <%= render partial: "step1", locals: { user: @user } %>
<% else %>
  <%
    case @user.current_step
    when "step2"
      render partial: "step2", locals: { user: @user }
    when "step3"
      render partial: "step3", locals: { user: @user }
    when "step4"
      render partial: "step4", locals: { user: @user }
    end
  %>
<% end %>
```

My logs show that is rendering the correct partial, but I don't see anything on the page.

```
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/checkout
  Rendered users/_step2.html.erb (1.9ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/checkout (4.5ms)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Nothing, I don't see any other log entry.  I have /checkouts/_contact_information.html.erb so the file is there?

Comment: You're not printing/displaying anything-see the difference with your other render statement?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `=` in your `case` statement:

```
<%=
  case @user.current_step
  when "step2"
    render partial: "step2", locals: { user: @user }
  when "step3"
    render partial: "step3", locals: { user: @user }
  when "step4"
    render partial: "step4", locals: { user: @user }
  end
%>
```

Although, if the content of `@user.current_step` is always going to match the name of the partial (as in your example) you could just use that and skip the `case` statement, like this:

```
<%= render partial: @user.current_step, locals: { user: @user } %>
```